# How to add sorting to this query (Order By DESC)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    IP, count(*) as cnt
FROM
   withdraw_update wu 
        JOIN
    update_detail u ON wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID
group by 1
having count(*) > 1   LIMIT 10 ;
```

It returns two columns :

```
IP | Cnt
```

I want the results of Cnt to be sorted(DESCENDING)

So i tried,

```
SELECT 
    IP, count(*) as cnt
FROM
   withdraw_update wu 
        JOIN
    update_detail u ON wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID
group by 1 DESC
having count(*) > 1   LIMIT 10 ;
```

Which doesn't make any changes.

I also tried:

```
SELECT 
    IP, count(*) as cnt
FROM
   withdraw_update wu 
        JOIN
    update_detail u ON wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID
group by 1 
having count(*) > 1 ORDER BY cnt DESC  LIMIT 10 ;
```

But the column values returned for **cnt** were completely different stuffs.

Comment: "But the column values returned for cnt were completely different stuffs..." This is because previously you were not ordering so the limit was just returning 10 "random" records  the order by is now happening first and then the limit which is why results are different.

Comment: Why do you want 10 random rows?

Comment: @Zane it was a mistake, after seeing the answer from XQbert, i put LIMIT 10 after last statement. I need limit to return only the top 10 rows after the sorting. Thanks for highlighting again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the same results ordered the way you want though not likely the best. method

- It suffers from having to do an inner select.
- It also suffers from trusting the database will order them the same way each time.

.

```
Select * from (
SELECT 
    IP, count(*) as cnt
FROM
   withdraw_update wu 
        JOIN
    update_detail u ON wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID
group by 1
having count(*) > 1   LIMIT 10) sub
order by cnt desc ;
```

Comment: This is technically a way to get what you are looking for. However why would you want 10 random rows?

Comment: That was my point on the original comment to the original post; but as you said this is technically the way to get what they were after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query (even though I don't like them cause they may affect the performance)

```
SELECT TBL.IP, TBL.CNT
FROM
(
SELECT 
    IP, count(*) as cnt
FROM
   withdraw_update wu 
        JOIN
    update_detail u ON wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID
group by 1
having count(*) > 1   LIMIT 10 ;
) AS TBL
ORDER BY TBL.CNT DESC
```

Comment: thanks for this option as well, i appreciate. Had to pick the first since it's very close to what i had i mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL Server? If yes, then i guess this should be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
   IP, 
   count(*) as cnt
FROM withdraw_update wu 
    JOIN update_detail u ON (wu.Update_ID = u.Update_ID)
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tag = mySQL.  mySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: Also this is missing a `GROUP BY`